# How to convert int[] into String[]

Tags: java

How to convert Int[] into String[] ?

I tried below method but it didn't work it seems

```
int[] abcd = new int[20];
String[] storetimearray = null;
storetimearray = new String[int.length];
```

Thanks

Comment: How should that code work? You're not doing anything with `abcd` and `storetimearray`. Just creating two arrays doesn't convert them.

Answer (score 0):

Tricks:

```
int[] abcd = new int[20];
String[] storetimearray = new String[abcd.length];//even put 20 here 
for(int i = 0;i < abcd.length; i++){
    storetimearray[i] = Integer.toString(abcd[i]);
}
```

Comment: abcd[i] + "" is very bad in performance, it need to convert and then come to stringbuilder to concat, you should use Integer.toString(num);

Comment: @Blackbelt sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

String[] strarr = Arrays.toString(yourIntArray).replaceAll("[\[\]]", "").split(",");

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the size of an array after you set its size and I dont think if this works: "abcd.length". Then:

```
    int arraySize = 20;
    int[] abcd = new int[arraySize];
    String[] storetimearray = new String[arraySize];
    for(int i = 0;i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        storetimearray[i] = String.valueOf(abcd[i]);
    }
```